# Can I submit a paper to ACM (proceeding) journal as for normal journal?

Tags: publications, acm

Is it possible to submit and publish a paper in the Proceedings of the ACM on Programming Languages (PACMPL) without attending any conference? Is PACMPL a journal that just publishes scientific papers which you can send to them?

Despite the extensive instructions on the LaTeX format that the publisher uses, I cannot find information on where and how to submit the paper.
I don't understand what you have to do to publish something in ACM.

Comment: The first paragraph of the author guidelines says to submit based on an appropriate [call for papers](https://dl.acm.org/journal/pacmpl/calls-for-papers) which are related to particular conferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot find information on where and how to submit the paper

For where and how to submit a manuscript, you must follow a [CFP: call for papers](https://dl.acm.org/journal/pacmpl/calls-for-papers) unlike other '*normal*' journals.

---

According to the Proceedings of the [ACM on Programming Languages (PACMPL) website](https://dl.acm.org/journal/pacmpl/editorial-message-vol1-icfp), about page, in reference to the inaugural editorial, PACMPL
"*is designed to supplant conference publication by moving to a journal model. PACMPL will be ***comprised of special issues***, each devoted to an area previously ***covered by a major conference***.*"

This is rehashed on [PACMPL site](https://dl.acm.org/journal/pacmpl):
"*Each issue of the journal is devoted to a particular subject area within programming languages and will be announced through publicized Calls for Papers*"

Elsevier has its [Procedia](https://www.elsevier.com/books-and-journals/procedia), while Springer has similar with the likes of [LNCS](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs)

Comment: Thank you. So I wasted my time, because I started by adapting my paper to their Latex format guidelines. Now it turns out that I can't publish my paper there.